# Active Directory Additional DC is not involved in authentication process

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2019

In my company we have two domain controllers PDC (primary one), ADC (Additional one).
upon user authentication the Additional domain controller is not involved in any user authentication.

we have checked the replication and it's OK.
we have checked the DNS and it seems OK.

is there a place to check to see if some is wrong or not?

Comment: `not involved in any user authentication.` how are you validating that? You should be able to sinkhole the functional DC name and fqdn in the hosts file on a client and force authentication on the other DC. Also need to include the output of `nltest /dsgetdc:domain.name /server: otherDC`.

Comment: when we disconnected the primary DC clients failed in the authentication process

Comment: Does the sysvol / netlogon share are on both server and fully replicated ? In dcpromo I often see a replication error that prevent those share to be replicated and it will lead to client error.  It's a common issue I see often

Comment: The "other" DC is probably not advertising one or more nltest flags. Nltest can also be used to enable DC Locator logging. And querying the DC using nslookup. Lots of testing available.

Comment: initial sysvol replication happened? new dc advertising as global catalog?

Comment: tanks every one it was **sysvol replication** error

Comment: Check the fsmo roles